# CSS - Height 100% scroll out of the window with fixed position and overflow auto

Tags: css, scroll, height, overflow, css-position

I try to create a CSS page structure with various fixed blocs, as described below.
The "scrollcontent" div have margins in order to avoid fixed div overlapping.

My problem is that "subscrollcontent" div inside "scrollcontent" has a 100% height that makes the scroll going further than the window height. I would need a "Height = 100% - 115px". I tried calc() function but it's not working and doesn't seems a good approach.

```
<head><title></title>
<style>
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width: 100%; }
div.wrapper { height:100%; width: 100%; background: #aaa; }
div.fixedleft{ position: fixed; top:0px; left:0px; float: left; width: 180px; height:100%; padding: 10px; background: #5b99fb;}
div.fixedtop1{ position: fixed; top:0px; left:0px; margin-left:200px; height: 20px; right:0px; padding: 5px; background: #ff6a00; overflow:hidden;}
div.fixedtop2{ position: fixed; top:0px; left:0px; margin-left:200px; margin-top:30px; height: 75px; right:0px; padding: 5px; background: #b200ff; overflow:hidden;}
div.scrollcontent{ position: static; margin-left:200px; margin-top: 115px;  padding: 0px; background: #f00; height:100%; right:0px; overflow:auto; }
div.subscrollcontent{ position: fixed; float:left; padding: 5px;  width:150px; height:100%; overflow:auto;  background: #0f0; }
div.scrollcontent2{ position: static; padding-left: 160px;}
</style>    
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1" style="height: 100%">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="fixedleft"></div>
<div class="fixedtop1"></div>
<div class="fixedtop2"></div>

<div class="scrollcontent">
      <div class="subscrollcontent"></div>
      <div class="scrollcontent2"></div>
</div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand why are you using position fixed for all your elements ...

Comment: Because I want these elements to be always on screen, even when scrolling "scrollcontent". I think I found the solution, replacing height:100% by "bottom:0px; top:105px;"